# Create a unique id for email confirmation

Tags: java, passwords

I need to create a unique ID for email confirmation, so when the customer click on the link it takes them to a page  to enter their email, once they entered their emails, an email will be sent to them.
A link is included in the email and by getting into the link they can change their password.
its the process , but I need you to confirm my steps, first I generate a random number and add it to db associated to user's id, if that page is opened then I allow them to change password right ?

Comment: Every time you generate that "random number", you need to check if it has already been generated and not used. This is to ensure you don't ever have duplicate ID. (even if the chances are very small, IMO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your procedure is almost correct. You should take care of following points though:

1) Make the key unpredictable, so that even with knowledge of the code, nobody can create it's own valid key. Since you are storing the key in the database anyway, you can create a "really-random" key, that's much better than using known values, like email and userid. Password reset functions are often the weakest link in the security of a web application.

```
// this (untested) code reads from the OS random source to create a random id
function createRandomKey($length)
{
  $buffer = mcrypt_create_iv($length, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
  $encodedBuffer = base64_encode($buffer);
  return substr($encodedBuffer, 0, $length);
}
```

2) Do not store this random-key in the database directly, instead handle it like a password and store a hash from it. That helps in case that an attacker can read your database (SQL-injection), even then he won't get all the keys for free.

3) Give each key an expiry date, so "forgotten" keys cannot be used anymore.

4) A password reset key should be removed after using it, so delete it from the database after the password was successfully changed.

Edit:

Sorry, i missed the Java tag in your question and my example is in PHP. Unfortunately i cannot provide an example in Java, but the principle is the same.

Comment: Suppose in `MySql` the `expiry` date comes up and the token is still not used, how/which service should be responsible for handling the deletion of `token`?

Comment: @TheCoder - That's up to you, you can either 1) keep the expired tokens 2) delete them when the user tries to use an expired token 3) installing a cron job removing the expired tokens periodically. I prefer solution 1, so I can inform the user that the reset expired and a new token should be generated. Every now and then I delete tokens which are older than a year or so.

Comment: Is that the same reason I get same verification token if I go to forget password on some websites/app? They resend the previous(unused) token of me.

Comment: @TheCoder - It sounds like they have one field in the user table for such a reset token, but that's not what I would recommend. I prefer the solution with a dedicated table for reset tokens, which is independend of the user table. There you can place as many tokens as you want, with userid and expiry date, and you dont' have to touch the user row.

Comment: "which is independend of the user table" -  not even the 1:1 relation of `User` and `Token` tables?

Comment: @TheCoder - Just meant that I wouldn't place he token inside the user table. You need the userid though, so this already _is_ a relation to the user table.

Answer (score 3):

Use a java.util.UUID for this.

Comment: I believe there are still chances of being not unique. (even if it's very small)

Comment: Your code could be altered by cosmic radiation or your server hit by meteorite, there are also chances for that

Comment: @user1129335 64 bits are sufficient to number every molecule in the universe. A UUID has 128 bits, which is sufficient to number every molecule in 2^64 universes. At what point do you start to consider your objection futile?

Answer (score 0):

I've used PHP for this. I generally created a hash of some sort of tracking info I can verify later. Like using an MD5 or SHA1 hash on the Email Address, or user ID. Or if you want you can just combine the two:

Java Script: `hex_md5(random_number + user_id + something_else);`

PHP: `md5($email.$userID.$unique_server_key);`

That should give you a unique key to track them by. Save this in your database as well as the variables used to generate it so you can track it later. I highly suggest the PHP version as since its server-side it will help keep malicious users from knowing your token generation algorithm.

JavaScript hash library:
http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/

EDIT:
Sorry, I too assumed the wrong language. For java you need to use a crypto library to generate a hash. Try this code (untested, I just typed it in)

```
import java.security.*;
.....
string hash = unique_salt_key.concat(user_id).concat(email);
byte[] hashBytes = hash.getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] emailCrypt = md.digest(hashBytes);
string emailToken = new String(emailCrypt)
```

I believe thats the correct use of the MD5. I just use the variables user_id and email as they are allready saved in your database. And using more then one constant from the database is best. Sorry if I'm a bit rusty on my java.

Comment: Is your variable `$unique_server_key` unique per server, or unique per password-reset-action?

Comment: unique per server. It's optional and just acts like a salt for the hash. It's a part that the user shouldn't be able to guess. If I know a users email and user ID I can try and make my own hash, but with the salt part added I really wouldn't be able to generate one to match.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.security.*;
.....
string hash = unique_salt_key.concat(user_id).concat(email);
byte[] hashBytes = hash.getBytes("UTF-8");
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] emailCrypt = md.digest(hashBytes);
string emailToken = new String(emailCrypt)



How to decrypt it again to get user_id and email?
```